# Issue when updating plots in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

So yet again I am struggling with Bokeh, and this time with `callbacks` from a `Select`-menu...

Below is a working example having categorical data. The plotting works fine, but when trying to change the category (from the `Select` object), nothing happens! I can't really understand what I am doing wrong here...

```
import pandas as pd
import math
import numpy as np

from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange, Select
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral5
from bokeh.layouts import layout, widgetbox

import random

""" Coloring based on universe """
index_cmap = factor_cmap('x', palette=Spectral5, factors=['Universe_1', 'Universe_2'], start=1)

universe_list = []
category_list_1 = []
category_list_2 = []
category_dependence = {'a' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'b' : ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H'], 'c' : ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L']}

N = 20

for x in range(N):
    universe_list.append(random.choice(['Universe_1', 'Universe_2']))
    category_list_1.append(random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c']))
    # Category 2 is dependent on Category 1
    category_list_2.append(random.choice(category_dependence[category_list_1[-1]]))

data = pd.DataFrame({'X' : category_list_1, 'Y' : category_list_2, 'Z' : np.random.randint(0,N,size=(N, 1)).flatten().tolist(), 'W' : universe_list})
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset=['X','Y','W'])

# Dropdown choices
dropdown_choices = sorted(data['X'].drop_duplicates().tolist())
menu_dropdown = Select(title="Category", options=dropdown_choices, value='a')

def select_category():

    val = menu_dropdown.value 
    selected = data.copy()

    return selected[selected.X.str.contains(val)==True]

def create_plot():

    df_ = select_category()

    x = zip(df_['Y'], df_['W'])
    y = df_['Z'].values
    legend = df_['W'].tolist()

    """ Create new figure... """
    p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*x), y_range=(0.0, round(y.max()*1.1,0)), plot_height=500, plot_width=800, title='Some fancy title...', toolbar_location=None, tools="hover")
    p.x_range.range_padding = 0.1
    p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/3
    p.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = "0pt"
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

    plot_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, top=y, legend=legend))
    p.vbar(x='x', top='top', width=0.9, source=plot_source, line_color="white", legend='legend', fill_color=index_cmap)

    return p

def update():
    l.children[1] = create_plot()  

controls = [menu_dropdown]
for control in controls:
    control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update)

inputs = widgetbox(*controls, sizing_mode='fixed')
l = layout([inputs, create_plot()], sizing_mode='fixed') 
show(l)
```

As of the above code, I thought of creating a new plot each time the user makes a change to the `Select` object, since the x-/y-axis and all categories will be different - instead of just changing the `plot_source` (right or wrong...).

Any help would be very much appreciated...

Comment: You are trying to run *real actual Python code* in your callbacks. That will require creating and [running a Bokeh Server Application](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html), as opposed to the standalone (pure HTML+JS) document that you have made above. Running real python code on events is the purpose of the Bokeh Server. The browser has no notion of Python or ability to run Python code.

Comment: @bigreddot Fair point. However, I still can't seem to be able to run it, even when I add "from bokeh.plotting import curdoc", substituting my "show(l)" with "curdoc().add_root(l)" and run the server as "bokeh serve --show categories.py". Clues on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually calling your `update` function in the lambda. This line:

```
control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update)
```

should instead be this:

```
control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())
```

Tho I will mention as of version `0.12.14` (released today) it should also work to update the data and factors on the existing plot, instead of replacing the plot wholesale.